# How can I use react-query in a React class component?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I realised: If I want to use hooks `import { useQuery } from 'react-query'` I can only do that in React function components.

Do I have to rewrite my old class components in the React function syntax, or is there an easy way to use react-query with the class syntax?

I'm sure it's documented somewhere, but I could only find tutorials using React function components.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It’s quite easy to re-implement it with a render props pattern. From a [github discussion](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/discussions/1558):

```
function UseQuery (props) {
  return props.children(useQuery(props.key, props.fn, props.options))
}
<UseQuery
  key=“todos”
  fn={() => getTodos()}
  options={{ staleTime: 5000 }}
>
  {query => {. . .}}
</UseQuery>
```

Comment: how to initialize it in app.js

Comment: prop key was undefined for me I think because it's used by React for component reference.

Answer (score 0):

as an extension to TkDodo's answer: In case you wonder how to correctly type this HOC using typescript:

```js
import { useQuery, QueryKey, QueryFunction, UseQueryOptions, UseQueryResult } from 'react-query';

type Props<
  TQueryFnData = unknown,
  TError = unknown,
  TData = TQueryFnData,
  TQueryKey extends QueryKey = QueryKey
> = {
  queryKey: TQueryKey;
  queryFn: QueryFunction<TQueryFnData, TQueryKey>;
  options?: Omit<UseQueryOptions<TQueryFnData, TError, TData, TQueryKey>, 'queryKey' | 'queryFn'>;
  children: (params: UseQueryResult<TData, TError>) => JSX.Element;
};

/**
 * Utility component for using React-Query in class components
 */
export const UseQuery = <
  TQueryFnData = unknown,
  TError = unknown,
  TData = TQueryFnData,
  TQueryKey extends QueryKey = QueryKey
>(
  props: Props<TQueryFnData, TError, TData, TQueryKey>
) => {
  const query = useQuery(props.queryKey, props.queryFn, props.options);
  return props.children(query);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Officially hooks (in general) can be only used inside functional React components. [See FAQs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html)

You can:

- rewrite your component (this is probably something that worth it on the long run… there are many other interesting hooks libs out there)
- try to isolate the code that needs react-query to a functional super-component. This can be hard but it depends on your code. Please note that hooks are not black magic, they are a pattern so it is possible to use them as HOC (Google for "use hooks in class component" and you'll find many examples).

Comment: Neither of these points are correct. To the first bullet, one of the main benefits of React and their upgrades is that old syntax (like class based components) will always work. If you have old class components that haven't been updated in years and work fine, just leave them be.

Second, just follow the example by TKDodo above.