# How to use useQuery in React JS class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, graphql, apollo-client

I am creating an application that only allows using React JS class component. UseQuery works only with function components, and the Query tag is deprecated. How can I get the data?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65609409/how-can-i-use-react-query-in-a-react-class-component) is what you are looking for?

Comment: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/examples#react-class-components Likely this ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that works for me is using  tag that is imported from @apollo/client/react/components. and here is where I got this information.
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/migrating/apollo-client-3-migration/